# Cocos2d - Strange CCMenu and CCMenuItem Behavior - Incorrect Hit Test Layer Order

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've encountered a strange quirk of CCMenu and CCMenuItem that may or may not be part of the cocos2d library on purpose, so I'm not sure if I should report it as a bug.

When two CCMenu items overlap, the one added to the menu last shows its image/texture above the other.
Ex:

```
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1, item2, nil]; 
// item2 will appear to be on top of item 1
```

Interestingly, touching item2 where the overlap occurs triggers item1's selector or block. Why is it that the item visually higher in the layer tier is actually lower when testing for touches? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the code for CCMenu and discovered that this occurs because when testing for the touches the CCMenu goes through its children array and returns the first one it finds that passes a hit test.

The second button appears on top of the first the same way every child works in cocos2d. As long as they all have the same z order, the last added is displayed on top.

I'm not sure if this is a bug but I did find a suggested fix on the cocos2d forums you could try. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8554

Comment: The solution on that page works perfectly. I'm not certain why that isn't the default functionality, but hopefully they will take a look at that in the future. Thanks!